# docker stats shows abnormal Block I/O usage, how to understand the Block I/O?

Tags: docker

Docker ce is used in a centos server to run a hadoop virtual cluster, and I want to get IO statistics from command `docker stats`.

But `Block I/O` always show a data inconsistent with expectations.

When a 2G file upload to hdfs, there is only little change in `Block I/O` but about 2G change in `Net I/O`, and the data file can be found in container of datanode.

When run `dd if=/dev/zero of=hello.txt bs=1000M count=1 oflag=direct` in container, above 3G data incresing in output of `Net I/O`.

from the docker docs, the Block I/O means:

> The amount of data the container has read to and written from block devices on the host

why `Block I/O` in `docker stats` and disk writing data not consistent?

or any better monitor tools should be used?